# Showing and hiding items based on a parent's value

Tags: knockout.js

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/BgdaF/)

---

I have an array of questions in my model, with the following attributes:

- **id**: simple enough, the ID of the question
- **text**: again, the text for the question
- **parents**: an array of question IDs that this question is dependent on
- **activators**: an array of strings that when a parent's answer is one of these values - this question is shown
- **answer**: the answer for this question
- **visible**: a boolean dictating whether this question should be visible on the form

I'm using `ko.mapping` to bind a JSON string (of which I'm retrieving from an asmx web method) to my view model.

I have a bunch of *primary* questions that have no `parents` or `activators` as these should always be visible, then a bunch of *dependent* questions that depend on their respective parent(s) having a certain value before the dependent is visible. This can extend as far as depdendents being dependent on dependents (if you see what I mean).

My initial thought (as I'm slowly getting there with knockout.js) was to subscribe to the `answer` property of my `question` and then grab a sub-set of questions that depend on the one just answered. Then have a look at the value, compare them with the activators and show / hide as necessary.

```
viewModel.questions().forEach(function (question) {
    question.answer.subscribe(function (value) {
        var dependents = viewModel.questions().filter(function (q) {
            return q.parents() && q.parents().indexOf(question.id()) !== -1;
        });
        
        dependents.forEach(function (d) {
            if (d.activators() && d.activators().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                d.visible(true);
            } else {
                d.visible(false);
                d.answer(null);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

While this works, I can't help feeling that I'm missing a trick here. I have to use `ko.mapping` to bind the model to my view model as it's already been created for me in the asmx method, so I have to extend my view model (as i'm doing here by cycling through all `questions` and subscribing to each one.

Maybe I should be using a `ko.computed` for the **visible** property, or maybe I should be creating some kind of custom `ko.bindingHandlers` instead? I'm not sure. What is the *correct* way of trying to achieve what I want?

Comment: can you please explain what's your final goal? i couldn't get it

Comment: You say it works, so what do you feel like you are missing? This looks like a perfectly fine solution. You have no DOM access in your viewmodel, you have a subscription taking taking of updating dependents (meaning it won't run too eagerly, or with too large a scope), and it behaves the way you want it to. What improvements would you like to see?

Comment: @Tyrsius You make a good point. I suppose my issue is that I'm having to go looking for the dependents to show / hide. From what I've learned of Knockout so far, that doesn't feel very Knockouty [sic]. I would've thought it more... *correct* that each object would keep track of its parents and show / hide itself?

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann That would certainly be one way to do it, but I don't think it would be more *correct*. The questions are an array, not a tree. The "dependenents" aren't children. To track them, they would have to have knowledge of them somehow, and with your flat structure that would require them knowing about their parents. Unless you plan on restructuring the data into a tree, I think you have the "correct" solution already.

Comment: Further, I don't think objects knowing about their parents is the right way to go. If it was a tree, I would expect objects to track their own answer, and show or hide their *children*. Parent's know about their children, but usually the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving what you're after, one of them is using [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) like you mentioned.

Whether or not that's considered the most "Knockout-correct" way, I won't say, but it's a different approach and might give you some ideas at the very least. Here's one way of creating the binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hideIfIrrelevant = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var question = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if(!question.parents()) {
           $(element).show() // Always show the question if it has no parents
           return false;
        }

        var allQuestions = bindingContext.$root.questions();
        var parents = allQuestions.filter(function (q) {
            return question.parents().indexOf(q.id()) !== -1;
        });

        var shown = false;
        $.each(parents, function(i, parent) {
            if(parent.answer() && question.activators().indexOf(parent.answer()) != -1) {
                shown = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if(shown) {
            $(element).show();
        }
        else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    }
};
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/BgdaF/3/) the updated fiddle. Note that by using the custom binding, you no longer need the `visible` property as part of your data model.

Comment: I really like this, having a custom binding makes the code more obvious from a reader's POV than subscribing to the answer, thanks!